# how much cpu and RAM is necessary for master and worker node for a microservices deployment with mongodb as database?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, microservices, aws-fargate

I build microservices in flask and mongodb and deployed in Minikube but want to deploy that app in production environment like managed kubernetes.

If I want to develop own cluster with two servers how much cpu and RAM is necessary for master and worker node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware requirements for K8s cluster strongly depend on applications running on said cluster. Different tools require different amount of memory or CPU. Estimated traffic also needs to be considered.

However, absolute minimum for cluster is 2GB of RAM for master node and 1GB of RAM for worker node. At least 1.5 CPU cores for master and 0.7 CPU core for worker.

Comment: Can I use scaling of nodes for external traffic ,if i initially start with single node with own cluster

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB Atlas has a free tier - the M0.